# How to pass multiple values in SavedInstanceState

Tags: android

I am trying to pass multiple values in SavedInstanceState. Can this be done?

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, array_counter);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(SAVED_ANSWER, answer);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(SAVED_VALUE, value);
}
```

but when receiving them in OnCreate they all have the same value:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        array_counter = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX);
        answer = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVED_ANSWER);
        value = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVED_VALUE);
    }
```

Comment: obvious reason: `KEY_INDEX.equals(SAVED_ANSWER) && SAVED_ANSWER.equals(SAVED_VALUE)` ... or you think that `onSaveInstanceState` is for saving(which is true ... but it is used by system only for certain reasons) ...

Comment: what are the values for KEY_INDEX, SAVED_ANSWER,SAVED_VALUE ?

Answer (score 0):

A `Bundle` is akin to a `HashMap<String, Object>`. So, you can put multiple values in them.

Most likely, either:

- Your testing is flawed (e.g., you are not testing a scenario where `savedInstanceState` is not `null`, and so the fields have their default values), or
- Your keys are identical, and so you are storing only one net item in the `Bundle`, or
- The values all happened to be the same when you put them into the `Bundle`

You might put breakpoints in `onCreate()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` and inspect the `Bundle` you work with in both places.